# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, ssl, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception

I'm running a local test against a remote endpoint with the following code:

```
        URL url = new URL(remoteEndpointUrl);
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((login + ":"+ password).getBytes("UTF-8"));  //Java 8
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        conn.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getResponseCode();
```

And this works flawlessly on my Mac OS which has the following Java version

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, 
mixed mode)
```

Now, if I take this and run it inside a docker container running with an `openjdk:8u151` image (which I launched from my Mac OS as well) I end up hitting the following exception:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:162)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2033)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
```

Apparently it doesn't seem to be ANY differences between my local TLS default settings and the ones inside the docker container. This is the debug output from running with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`:

**Local output:**

```
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    main, setSoTimeout(0) called
    main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=example.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=example.com)
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    %% No cached client session
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1541229707 bytes = { 122, 255, 53, 110, 142, 33, 132, 23, 192, 232, 102, 11, 200, 33, 185, 187, 146, 150, 134, 215, 2, 72, 62, 10, 76, 46, 224, 66 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=example.com]
    ***
    [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 198
    0000: 01 00 00 C2 03 03 5C DD   4D 8B 7A FF 35 6E 8E 21  ......\.M.z.5n.!
    0010: 84 17 C0 E8 66 0B C8 21   B9 BB 92 96 86 D7 02 48  ....f..!.......H
    0020: 3E 0A 4C 2E E0 42 00 00   3A C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  >.L..B..:.#.'.<.
    0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
    0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
    0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
    0060: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 5F 00   0A 00 16 00 14 00 17 00  ......_.........
    0070: 18 00 19 00 09 00 0A 00   0B 00 0C 00 0D 00 0E 00  ................
    0080: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00   0D 00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06  ................
    0090: 01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04   01 04 02 03 03 03 01 03  ................
    00A0: 02 02 03 02 01 02 02 00   00 00 1B 00 19 00 00 16  ................
    00B0: 73 75 6D 69 74 64 65 76   2E 6D 79 73 68 6F 70 69  example.com
    00C0: 66 79 2E 63 6F 6D
    main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 198
    [Raw write]: length = 203
    0000: 16 03 03 00 C6 01 00 00   C2 03 03 5C DD 4D 8B 7A  ...........\.M.z
    0010: FF 35 6E 8E 21 84 17 C0   E8 66 0B C8 21 B9 BB 92  .5n.!....f..!...
    0020: 96 86 D7 02 48 3E 0A 4C   2E E0 42 00 00 3A C0 23  ....H>.L..B..:.#
    0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
    0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
    0050: C0 2D C0 31 00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
    0060: C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 5F 00 0A 00 16  ..........._....
    0070: 00 14 00 17 00 18 00 19   00 09 00 0A 00 0B 00 0C  ................
    0080: 00 0D 00 0E 00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00 00 0D 00 1C  ................
    0090: 00 1A 06 03 06 01 05 03   05 01 04 03 04 01 04 02  ................
    00A0: 03 03 03 01 03 02 02 03   02 01 02 02 00 00 00 1B  ................
    00B0: 00 19 00 00 16 73 75 6D   69 74 64 65 76 2E 6D 79  .....example.com
    [Raw read]: length = 5
    0000: 16 03 03 00 57                                     ....W
    [Raw read]: length = 87
    0000: 02 00 00 53 03 03 5C DD   4D 8B A2 3C 5D 36 46 82  ...S..\.M..<]6F.
    0010: BE 0E 5E DA 23 05 66 D5   1B AE 13 AA 8F 98 12 30  ..^.#.f........0
    0020: DF 52 9C 28 AA 7B 20 43   4F 5E 40 8C B4 C4 1E 26  .R.(.. CO^@....&
    0030: 4F 5D B8 3D 39 16 D5 56   41 9C B0 F8 D5 F4 2A 55  O].=9..VA.....*U
    0040: B3 0A E9 A2 6F 9D 88 C0   2B 00 00 0B FF 01 00 01  ....o...+.......
    0050: 00 00 0B 00 02 01 00                               .......
    main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 87
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1541229707 bytes = { 162, 60, 93, 54, 70, 130, 190, 14, 94, 218, 35, 5, 102, 213, 27, 174, 19, 170, 143, 152, 18, 48, 223, 82, 156, 40, 170, 123 }
    Session ID:  {67, 79, 94, 64, 140, 180, 196, 30, 38, 79, 93, 184, 61, 57, 22, 213, 86, 65, 156, 176, 248, 213, 244, 42, 85, 179, 10, 233, 162, 111, 157, 136}
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Compression Method: 0
    Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
    Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
    ***
    %% Initialized:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
    ** TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 87ere
```

**Inside docker container output:**

```
    Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
    Allow legacy hello messages: true
    Is initial handshake: true
    Is secure renegotiation: false
    Test worker, setSoTimeout(0) called
    Test worker, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=example.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=example.com)
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
    %% No cached client session
    *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
    RandomCookie:  GMT: 1541242532 bytes = { 118, 119, 70, 101, 0, 69, 160, 231, 254, 159, 164, 222, 99, 67, 81, 99, 102, 20, 11, 71, 1, 162, 231, 238, 141, 93, 75, 42 }
    Session ID:  {}
    Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
    Compression Methods:  { 0 }
    Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
    Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=example.com]
    ***
    [write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 208
    0000: 01 00 00 CC 03 03 5C DD   7F A4 76 77 46 65 00 45  ......\...vwFe.E
    0010: A0 E7 FE 9F A4 DE 63 43   51 63 66 14 0B 47 01 A2  ......cCQcf..G..
    0020: E7 EE 8D 5D 4B 2A 00 00   64 C0 24 C0 28 00 3D C0  ...]K*..d.$.(.=.
    0030: 26 C0 2A 00 6B 00 6A C0   0A C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0  &.*.k.j.....5...
    0040: 0F 00 39 00 38 C0 23 C0   27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29 00  ..9.8.#.'.<.%.).
    0050: 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13 00   2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33 00  g.@...../.....3.
    0060: 32 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 00   9D C0 2E C0 32 00 9F 00  2.,.+.0.....2...
    0070: A3 C0 2F 00 9C C0 2D C0   31 00 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0  ../...-.1.......
    0080: 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00   16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00  ................
    0090: 3F 00 0D 00 1C 00 1A 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ?...............
    00A0: 03 04 01 04 02 03 03 03   01 03 02 02 03 02 01 02  ................
    00B0: 02 00 00 00 1B 00 19 00   00 16 73 75 6D 69 74 64  ..........
    00C0: 65 76 2E 6D 79 73 68 6F   70 69 66 79 2E 63 6F 6D  example.com
    Test worker, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 208
    [Raw write]: length = 213
    0000: 16 03 03 00 D0 01 00 00   CC 03 03 5C DD 7F A4 76  ...........\...v
    0010: 77 46 65 00 45 A0 E7 FE   9F A4 DE 63 43 51 63 66  wFe.E......cCQcf
    0020: 14 0B 47 01 A2 E7 EE 8D   5D 4B 2A 00 00 64 C0 24  ..G.....]K*..d.$
    0030: C0 28 00 3D C0 26 C0 2A   00 6B 00 6A C0 0A C0 14  .(.=.&.*.k.j....
    0040: 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F 00 39   00 38 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C  .5.....9.8.#.'.<
    0050: C0 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40   C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04  .%.).g.@...../..
    0060: C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2C   C0 2B C0 30 00 9D C0 2E  ...3.2.,.+.0....
    0070: C0 32 00 9F 00 A3 C0 2F   00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00 9E  .2...../...-.1..
    0080: 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A   C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13  ................
    0090: 00 FF 01 00 00 3F 00 0D   00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06 01  .....?..........
    00A0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   04 02 03 03 03 01 03 02  ................
    00B0: 02 03 02 01 02 02 00 00   00 1B 00 19 00 00 16 73  ...............s
    00C0: 75 6D 69 74 64 65 76 2E   6D 79 73 68 6F 70 69 66  example.com
    00D0: 79 2E 63 6F 6D                                     
    [Raw read]: length = 5
    0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
    [Raw read]: length = 2
    0000: 02 28                                              .(
    Test worker, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
    Test worker, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
    Test worker, called closeSocket()
    Test worker, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failureere
```

Now, i've tried to set the security property `crypto.policy` to `unlimited` according to https://www.petefreitag.com/item/844.cfm which is supposed to easy-enable JCE (Java Cryptographic Extension) which I got the lead from: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https but it still fails.

I've been long battled this and have no clue what to check anymore as both executions are using `TLSv1.2` as the https protocol and both are using the same cipher suites so any idea why is it failing inside the docker?

Any help is much appreciated, 
Thanks in advance

**Edit** : Running with `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false` on my Mac OS

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
main, the previous server name in SNI (type=host_name (0), value=example.com) was replaced with (type=host_name (0), value=example.com)
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1541432023 bytes = { 91, 55, 180, 242, 51, 13, 227, 239, 109, 218, 210, 217, 65, 181, 16, 146, 251, 182, 30, 23, 156, 83, 207, 5, 80, 0, 133, 88 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=example.com]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 134
0000: 01 00 00 82 03 03 5C E0   63 D7 5B 37 B4 F2 33 0D  ......\.c.[7..3.
0010: E3 EF 6D DA D2 D9 41 B5   10 92 FB B6 1E 17 9C 53  ..m...A........S
0020: CF 05 50 00 85 58 00 00   1A 00 3C 00 67 00 40 00  ..P..X....<.g.@.
0030: 2F 00 33 00 32 00 9C 00   9E 00 A2 00 0A 00 16 00  /.3.2...........
0040: 13 00 FF 01 00 00 3F 00   0D 00 1C 00 1A 06 03 06  ......?.........
0050: 01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04   01 04 02 03 03 03 01 03  ................
0060: 02 02 03 02 01 02 02 00   00 00 1B 00 19 00 00 16  ................
0070: 73 75 6D 69 74 64 65 76   2E 6D 79 73 68 6F 70 69  example.com
0080: 66 79 2E 63 6F 6D                                  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 134
[Raw write]: length = 139
0000: 16 03 03 00 86 01 00 00   82 03 03 5C E0 63 D7 5B  ...........\.c.[
0010: 37 B4 F2 33 0D E3 EF 6D   DA D2 D9 41 B5 10 92 FB  7..3...m...A....
0020: B6 1E 17 9C 53 CF 05 50   00 85 58 00 00 1A 00 3C  ....S..P..X....<
0030: 00 67 00 40 00 2F 00 33   00 32 00 9C 00 9E 00 A2  .g.@./.3.2......
0040: 00 0A 00 16 00 13 00 FF   01 00 00 3F 00 0D 00 1C  ...........?....
0050: 00 1A 06 03 06 01 05 03   05 01 04 03 04 01 04 02  ................
0060: 03 03 03 01 03 02 02 03   02 01 02 02 00 00 00 1B  ................
0070: 00 19 00 00 16 73 75 6D   69 74 64 65 76 2E 6D 79  .....example.com
0080: 73 68 6F 70 69 66 79 2E   63 6F 6D                 
[Raw read]: length = 5 
0000: 16 03 03 00 51                                     ....Q
[Raw read]: length = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 03 5C E0   63 DA 99 74 67 FF 71 48  ...M..\.c..tg.qH
0010: B5 9B 8F 63 A4 06 15 AE   1D E6 1B CA 27 C6 9C 85  ...c........'...
0020: B8 E8 40 03 89 54 20 29   3F 81 6A E8 E4 54 39 D7  ..@..T )?.j..T9.
0030: 5A 95 5B DD 7C 59 18 28   05 C2 49 75 22 2E 69 78  Z.[..Y.(..Iu".ix
0040: E1 1B 11 62 03 62 C0 00   9C 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  ...b.b..........
0050: 00                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1541432026 bytes = { 153, 116, 103, 255, 113, 72, 181, 155, 143, 99, 164, 6, 21, 174, 29, 230, 27, 202, 39, 198, 156, 133, 184, 232, 64, 3, 137, 84 }
Session ID:  {41, 63, 129, 106, 232, 228, 84, 57, 215, 90, 149, 91, 221, 124, 89, 24, 40, 5, 194, 73, 117, 34, 46, 105, 120, 225, 27, 17, 98, 3, 98, 192}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-4, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 81
```

Comment: can you get any logs on the server side ?

Comment: Did you also change the hex numbers in front of `example.com` to contain `example.com`, I have seen enough examples of people only changing the human readable version to an example domain, but then still leaving the original domain in the "binary debug" text, that is used when people reconstruct the actual SSL packets to see what's going wrong

Comment: @SvetlinZarev unfortunately no, its out of my reach.

Comment: @Ferrybig I didn't change the hex numbers, I just replaced my original endpoint to `example.com` to obscure the original endpoint, is that a problem?

Comment: can you add the full java version of your docker ?

Comment: I would first make sure that I run the exact same JVM version and from the same vendor. For example both must be Oracle or openjdk.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Indeed I only found a server side bug, which I mention in my answer. But a bit different, and this doesn't explain exacty how it is triggered.

Comment: to be exact `crypto.policy` is a _security_ property not a system property, but in the working case the server agrees an AES-128(GCM) suite so it isn't needed anyway.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for pointing out the difference I've tried it with setting the security property as well, with not luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but I hope it helps.

In the first case the client sends the two *Elliptic Curve extensions*, but not in the second. I don't know the reason of this different behaviour, but this probably ends with the server not being able to go further because of the impossibility to find a common cipher suite.

The [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt) gives 2 reasons that you shouldn't have any problem with that extensions missing :

1. The handshake failure is not mentionned as the default case if they are missing :

> If a server does not understand the Supported Elliptic Curves
>   Extension, does not understand the Supported Point Formats Extension, 
>   or is unable to complete the ECC handshake while restricting itself
>   to the enumerated curves and point formats, it MUST NOT negotiate the 
>   use of an ECC cipher suite.  Depending on what other cipher suites
>   are proposed by the client and supported by the server, this may
>   result in a fatal handshake failure alert due to the lack of common
>   cipher suites.

2. Sending them is not exactly mandatory, just a preferable behaviour with the '*SHOULD*' word :

> A TLS client that proposes ECC cipher suites in its ClientHello
>   message SHOULD include these extensions.

This leads to a software bug or a wrong install (missing files, wrong permissions,..) either on the client or the server.

What happens on your local test if you run it with `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false` ?

You can compare the contents of all directories in jre/lib to find anything missing maybe.

For example does your docker client contain the file `libsunec.so` ?

What TLS server is on your endpoint ? Is it dockerized too ?

At least the [Release Notes for JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html) doesn't mention any client side problem that would have been solved. But on the contrary it mentions a `jdk.tls.namedGroups(null)` problem solved in [8u131](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8all-relnotes-2226344.html#R180_131), the bug [JDK-8173783](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173783) which is nicely explained by its duplicate bug - the [JDK-8173960](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173960) bug. This doesn't explain why you are facing two different behaviors but maybe there's something around it that is not mentionned (another missing file rather `sunec.jar` said in the bug, leading to the same problem). From my point of view, a missing file on the client side leads to a server side bug (triggered by a missing file too or a simple software bug). Let us know the solution if you find.

Comment: I ran it with `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false` locally  and now I don't see `elliptic_curves` and `ec_point_formats` in the debug , however, the test finishes successfully. This means the absence of the Elliptic Curves extensions (in the docker execution) have nothing to do with the failure inside the container.

Comment: It must have something to do with if it is the only difference, no ? Or we miss something. `enableECC=false` probably also removes the EC cipher suites from the Client Hello cipher list. Would you please edit and post your new SSL trace with this test ? We will then see what Cipher is chosen by the server when EC is absent, and we will try forcing your docker to use this cipher suite only (with `https.protocols` system property) - all ciphers locally also appear in the docker's list, this one being even a bit longer.

Comment: I see your point, this is the trace: https://gist.github.com/antoniogomezalvarado/ba5ce4f9eff7414688142df19f546d46 but the https protocol is the same as before, what should I look for?

Comment: We see that the cipher suite list is now quite short without any EC, and the server has chosen `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. As suggested above (I was thinking about the cipher but gave the wrong property - sorry), can you try on docker with `-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` ?

Comment: WOW!! that actually worked! But `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` was in the cypher suites in the first place, does the order in the suites matter? why did I have to point a specific one among the list? Also `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` was agreed during the handshake in my local run, which also appears in the cipher suites for both executions, i'm confused, what am I missing?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter. I conclude my answer is almost good : there's something wrong on the server when receiving a Client Hello with EC cipher suites without the EC extensions. It is not compliant to the RFC. Either the bug I mentioned is the same thing, or it should be investigated further if you can check what's installed on the server.

Comment: similar problem (local vs docker) in my case Java 11, not sure if base docker image is important (debian:stretch-slim), but in debug logs seeing just ClientHello ⇢ Raw Write ⇢ Raw Read ⇢ READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2, HANDSHAKE_FAILURE.. Not even sure where to start analysing deeper, despite being able to follow solving of issue here... Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: @Ewoks There are many reasons for a handshake to fail. Try the above the solution, if it doesn't help open correctly a new Question (with the debug trace, the versions,..)

Comment: Fair enough, I opened new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523042/sslhandshakeexception-when-trying-to-access-es-instance-from-docker

Answer (score -2):

"Handshake failure" often means there is no overlap between the server's TLS level (e.g. TLS1.2) and cipher suites, and what your WebSphere can handle.

I'd run a test like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ against the server, then look at your QoP settings in WebSphere Security > SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations

[java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073940/java-lang-runtimeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal)

Comment: it's a copy/paste, posting a comment should be enough (or even flagging as a duplicate when you are 100% sure it's the very same thing)