# SSLHandshakeException when trying to access ES instance from Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate

I am trying to access 6.x ES instance using High Level REST Client 6.7.2.
Access to this ES instance is provided to me via hostname (https://****.azureedge.net), username & password.

My Spring Boot application is getting data from the same ES without issues when it runs from my dev environment (IDE), but throws SSLHandshakeException as soon as I try run it from Docker container (from my development machine or K8s cluster in cloud).

Container is made with base image: `FROM debian:stretch-slim` & `OpenJDK 11.0.2` with Spring Boot necessary modules.

I made some progress debugging with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. It turns out that while running in docker image just few first steps of usual SSL handshaking happen:

```
Produced ClientHello handshake message
WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 2352
Raw write
Raw read (0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28    ......(   )
READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
Received alert message (
  "Alert": {
    "level"      : "fatal",
    "description": "handshake_failure"
  }
)
```

followed by SSLHandshakeException:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:938)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:227)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1749)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1708)
at org.elasticsearch.client.SecurityClient.getSslCertificates(SecurityClient.java:508) 
....
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:271)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:316)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:509)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
```

When running from my local environment handshake looks uninterrupted:

```
Produced ClientHello handshake message
WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 460
Raw write
Raw read
READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 155
Consuming ServerHello
ServerHello
Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.3
Session initialized:  Session(1560119025211|TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
WRITE: TLS13 change_cipher_spec, length = 1
Raw write
Raw read
READ: TLSv1.2 change_cipher_spec, length = 1
Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
Raw read
READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 27
...
Raw read
READ: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 8469
Consuming server Certificate handshake message
... // here is the list of 3 certificates with "SHA256withRSA", "SHA256withRSA", "SHA1withRSA" signature algorithms
Found trusted certificate ⇢ SHA1withRSA
...
```

While running locally I noticed `CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=Washington, C=US`, as well as `CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root, OU=CyberTrust, O=Baltimore, C=IE` as issuers, maybe this is important, but I guess it is expected considering ES host address (Azure).

At the end I wanted to emphasise that I didn't need to do anything special to make this work in my **macOS** Java **11.0.2** development environment.

I already tried following, but that didn't change anything:

- Changing base Docker image from "slim" to non slim version
- Using OpenJDK 11.0.1 or 11.0.2
- Added cert from host to TrustStore that JVM is using in a runtime. (I checked in Docker container that there is indeed one more cert, but considering when **handshake failure** happens I imagine this is irrelevant)
- tried to enforce App with: "-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false", "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3", "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3", didn't help

**Interesting:** curl from Docker image with BasicAuth "talks" with same URL without issues (handshake completes) & small query returns results. I guess that curl and JVM are using different sources of trusted CAs inside the Docker, different algorithms for handshaking etc..

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Instead of slim base image, try with full image and see if that helps

Comment: that unfortunately didn't change anything: same Exception after same handshaking steps

Comment: Can you do a `curl -v <url>` and see if you get same handshake error inside the docker container

Comment: curl to ES instance & exact same URL with BasicAuth inside the Docker worked. I learned that curl inside docker uses `/etc/ssl/certs` and JVM `/JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` as source of trusted CAs (please correct me if I am wrong), so not sure if this little progress is actually useful.

Comment: Yes, see if this helps http://rabexc.org/posts/certificates-not-working-java and this too https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456475/adding-a-root-certification-authority-to-a-java-application

Comment: not sure how to get that cert-file :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194713/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-ewoks).

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR:** **enforcing TLSv1.2 for client** in the app made handshaking complete from inside the docker

After a lot of try/fail attempts I made it work. Following things didn't make any difference:

- using non "slim" debian base image insead of "slim"
- using OpenJDK 11.0.2 instead of 11.0.1
- adding host's certificate to JVM TrustedStore while building docker image so it is available when container starts.
- enforcing `com.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false`
- enforcing TLSv1.3 for `https.protocols` and/or `jdk.tls.client.protocols`
- enforcing TLSv1.2 for `https.protocols`

**What fixed** handshake with host, was enforcing TLSv1.2 for client by using `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` in Dockerfile, so app runs with this flag inside container. This allowed SSL handshake to complete as it should work anyways. For some reason actual negotiation about protocol version didn't work without enforcing lower version of protocol for client. Logs from local vs docker environment doesn't show any difference but this helped in docker.

What helped me to find out was:

- setting of `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` or even more detailed `javax.net.debug=all` so I could see details of handshake attempts
- confirming that "at least someone" can establish outbound communication from inside the docker by using curl to send same request as app is trying, which worked because curl somehow figured out how to proceed handshaking with host.
- pure luck

Thanks everyone for support & ideas

Comment: For someone else looking and being new at docker like me, in your docker file change your entrypoint to the following, it fixed it for me.
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2" ]